# how to dynamically change the latitude and longitude points and reflecting it on the map without reloading the map in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have looked to the solutions on stack exchange for this but not able to shape it up with my code. My code is :-

```
foreach($json_decode as $row){
        $lat_d= $row->Latitude;
        echo("\n");
        $long_d= $row->Longitude;

        }
        error_log($lat_d);
        error_log($long_d);
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api
/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var map;
        function initialize() {

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $lat_d; ?>, <?php echo $long_d; ?>);

            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: latlng,
                panControl: true,
                zoomControl: true,
                scaleControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }


           map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        <?php
           echo "addMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(".$lat_d.", ".$long_d."), map);";
        ?>

}
 function addMarker(latLng, map) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                draggable: true, // enables drag & drop
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });

            return marker;
        }

</script>
</head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div style="float:left; position:relative; width:550px; border:0px #000 solid;">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width:1421px;height:700px;border:solid black 1px;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code works only to show the single point on map. But can somebody help to tell me how the marker position can be changed depending on the changing latitude and longitude.
I am not able to separate the map with the contents .Everytime i try doing it using setInterval(), it reloads the entire map to me. I will be thankful if anybody can help me with this.
Please help me with this. I am stuck at this point.

Comment: Please wrap your php code.. And I don't see any `setInterval` in the code you posted..

Comment: I removed that sir. Because that was not giving me a desirabel output. I am taking suggestions from your side on how should i now set the code so as to dynamically change the  latitude and longitude

Comment: You're just setting one marker.. Is that what you're trying to do? You want to change lat & lng of that unique marker? Need to do so using PHP?

Comment: Yes sir.... I want this marker to change its place depending on the value of latitude and longitude obtained after a fixed time